# Splitting an email id and validating it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, string, split

I am new to ruby and want to ask that if I want to validate an email id in such a way that it is in the format 
`x.y@xyz.com` such that :-
x is 1 or 2 digits
y is day,days,month,months,hour hours --nothing else then this
@xyz.com -> it is only xyz.com

please provide me a logic for this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Provide a few example matches and mismatches.

Comment: Matches :-
2.days@xyz.com
3.months@xyz.com
22.hours@xyz.com


Mismatches:-
2.many@xyz.com --in place of many it should be day,days,month..etc
day.3@abc.in --in place of month it should be a digit,in place of 3 it should be month,months,days,etc.. in place of abc.in it should be xyz.com

Comment: You could make the question a bit clearer by including your above comment in it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `validate_format_of` for validating email in rails. And also can use same regexp  for ruby.

Like for rails, you can write in your model:

```
format = /^(\d|\d\d).(hour|hours|day|days|month|months|year|years)@xyz.com/
validate_format_of :email, :with => format
```

In regexp given above:
`\d|\d\d` means that email should begin from an one or two digit integer
after that there should be a dot(.) then `hour|hours|day|days|month|months|year|years` means after dot, there can be any value from hour, hours, day, days, month, months, year, years. And after this @xyz.com should be there in email address.

Some valid examples:

1.day@xyz.com

12.hours@xyz.com

4.months@xyz.com

1.year@xyz.com

Comment: This is assuming using `Rails` though

Comment: But i want to split it... I mean, make an object of digit and time_duration...
Like for 1.day@xyz.com
I want an object -> digit = 1, time_duration = day .... and another object mail_from=anyone@anymailserver.com

Comment: You can use this: `email = '1.day@xyz.com'; arr = email.split('.'); int_part = arr[0]; time_dur = arr[1].split('@')[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm...the RE should look something like

```
^(\d|\d\d)\.(day|days|month|months|hour|hours)@xyz\.com
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Many many thanks.. please provide me a full code that what I have to write...
Like a=2.days@xyz.com
and c=(\d|\d\d)\.(day|days|month|months|hour|hours)@xyz\.com
puts a.match .. Please, don't mind, i m new to this..

Comment: I'm sorry - I don't know precisely what you're trying to do and thus I really can't write your code for you.  It looks like you're off to a good start - take it one step at a time and I'm sure you'll get it.